# VueJS router espace "&" char then make query param fail

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to make sharable URI of my app, I'm working with vue router 3.

The problem is when I access my app using a route like

```
localhost:8000/foo?param1=yeaa&param2=yeaa2
```

This URI is caught by vue router but converted to

```
localhost:8000/logs?param1=yeaa&amp%3Bparam2=yeaa2
```

Then when I'm trying to access query params using

```
router.query.param1 // it works
router.query.param2 // it fail and return undefined
```

In fact when I check inside Vue devtools is can see vue router think the second param is `amp;param2`

```
$route
  path:"/logs"
  query:Object
    amp;param2:"yeaa2"
    param1:"yeaa"
  params:Object (empty)
  fullPath:"/logs?param1=yeaa&amp%3Bparam2=yeaa2"
  meta:Object (empty)
```

This is a little bit boring and I didn't success to find on the vue router doc if there is an option/config to avoid this.

FYI when I access the same URI with same param using a `router-link` this problem is gone.

Is there a way to avoid this char escaping, inside vue router config (maybe be not well informed in the doc) or with vanilla JS?

If not I think this is a vue router issue.

**EDIT**

There is where I create the route

```
{
component: Log,
path: '/logs',
props: route => ({
  oldQueryOptions: {
    absoluteTimeRangeFrom: route.query.absoluteTimeRangeFrom,
    absoluteTimeRangeTo: route.query.absoluteTimeRangeTo,
    query: route.query.query,
    rangeKeyword: route.query.rangeKeyword,
    relativeTimeRange: route.query.relativeTimeRange,
    type: route.query.type,
  },
}),
},
```

Comment: Need the code to the part where you create the url

Comment: @RuChernChong I edited the question with the route config code